# background-color changing(onclick) via javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, background-color

I was trying to code a background-changing effect in javascript where clicking on the button would change the background color.The catch was that I am supposed to be using an array of colors that would be the background-color. On each Click the button should loop the colors through the array. here is the code below:-

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>background-changer</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    button{
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }
    button:hover{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
</style>
<button onclick="ChangeBackground()">CHANGE COLOR</button>

<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'];

    function ChangeBackground(){
        backgrounds.forEach(strtChng);
    }

    function strtChng(){
        let i=0;
        if(i<=backgrounds.length){
            i++;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[i];
            console.log(backgrounds[i]);
        }
        else{
            i=0;
        }
    }
            
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THE CONSOLE ALSO SHOWS ROYALBLUE LOOPED 5 TIMES WHEN CLICKED ONCE.

Comment: _"not working"_ is not a helpful error/problem description. What happens? What should happen instead? Any errors in the console?

Comment: _"The `<style>` element **must be included inside the `<head>`** of the document."_ ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style))

Comment: `backgrounds.forEach(strtChng)` makes no sense

Comment: Do you want to change the color once on each click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter version using `addEventListener` and `modulo (%)`

```js
let backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'], i = 0
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[i%backgrounds.length]
  i++
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<button>CHANGE COLOR</button>
```

Comment: could you explain how the modulo worked out here? I tried the method given before but i had to click twice to repeat the cycle. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Well `modulo` works like it should, maybe lookup the docs. As for clicking twice, not sure but maybe it has something to do with the fact that you loop through your backgrounds array on each click

Comment: Probably. Thanks anyways. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the elements twice, while there is no need

```js
    const btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'];
    let i = 0;
    function ChangeBackground(){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[i];
            (i > backgrounds.length-2) ? i = 0 : i++
    }
```

```css
  body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    button{
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }
    button:hover{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <button onclick="ChangeBackground()">CHANGE COLOR</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes in your code.

Have a look snippet.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var backgrounds = ['red', 'royalblue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow'];
    var count = 0;

    function ChangeBackground(){

          if(count<=backgrounds.length){
            count++;
          }else {
             count=0;
          }
      
        strtChng(count);
   
    }



    function strtChng(i){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[i];
      console.log(backgrounds[i]);
    }
```

```css
body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    button{
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }
    button:hover{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="ChangeBackground()">CHANGE COLOR</button>
```